tailwind styles not properly applying in express and ejs app
I am using express and ejs view engine in my project and i want to implement the tailwind css in my code for better styling but the tailwind styles are either not applying completely or not all of the tailwind css styles are applying . This is my folder structure
-- api /
-----  index.js
-- node_modules
-- public/
-----  images
-----  css/
--------  style.css
--------  output.css
-- views/
-----  layouts/
--------  layout.ejs
-----  partials/
--------  header.ejs
--------  footer.ejs
-----  index.ejs
-- postcss.config.js
-- tailwind.config.js
-- vercel.json

this is my api/index.js code
const express = require("express");
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const { formValidationSchema } = require("../schemas/formvalidation");
const app = express();
const multer = require("multer");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require("dotenv").config();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("views", __dirname + "/../views");
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set("layout", __dirname + "/../views/layouts/layout.ejs");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

;

app.get("/", async function (req, res) {
  
  res.render("index", {
    title: "Welcome to my portfolio!",
    // Other data
  });
});

this is layout.ejs code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/output.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header><%- include('../partials/header') %></header>

    <main><%- body %></main>

    <footer><%- include('../partials/footer') %></footer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


tailwind.config.js file code
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./views/**/*.ejs"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};


postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};


and views/index.ejs file code
<div class="mt-20 flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-pink-400">
    <div class="!bg-[#f3f5f8] flex justify-between !w-[90vw] py-2 px-2">
        <div class="">Address</div>
        <div>11111111111</div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="text-purple-300">Digital Marketing Specialist</h1>
    <img src="/images/zee.png">

    <p>Name</p>
</div>

I first tried the build method described on tailwind website where we have to run a build command
npx tailwindcss -i ./public/css/style.css -o ./public/css/output.css --watch

but with this only few styles are being applied like bg-black is applying but bg-[#f3f5f8] is not applying or any custom bg color. also w-full on child divs are applying and padding is also not applying.
I then decided to use post css way also mention on tailwind so i installed post css and autoprefixer and made postcss.config.js file with the code mention above, but it still not worked.
I want to basically be able to style properly like we do in react or next js web app using tailwind
I first tried the build method described on tailwind website where we have to run a build command
npx tailwindcss -i ./public/css/style.css -o ./public/css/output.css --watch

but with this only few styles are being applied like bg-black is applying but bg-[#f3f5f8] is not applying or any custom bg color. also w-full on child divs are applying and padding is also not applying.
I then decided to use post css way also mention on tailwind so i installed post css and autoprefixer and made postcss.config.js file with the code mention above, but it still not worked.
I want to basically be able to style properly like we do in react or next js web app using tailwind
